# How do i pass date as parameter in Web Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql

I am currently wondering how i can pass date value to my Web Api?

A snippet of my code in the controller:

```
/// Example: /api/firearms/olderthan/2015-12-30
        [Route("olderthan/{olderthan}")]
        public IQueryable<FirearmDto> GetFirearmsByDateolderthan(string olderthan)
        {
            DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(olderthan);
            return db.Firearms
                .Where(f => f.LastUpdate <= temp)
                .Select(AsFirearmDto);
        }
```

I get the following Error as listed below:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at WriteArrayOfFirearmDtoToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract ) at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

Any help or insight to what i'm missing/ doing wrong would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You're sure the problem is with the date?  The error message suggests it failed to serialize the response.

Comment: The error appears to be on the serialization of the returned object. As it states, it is trying to serialize an integer property where the value is null. You may need to check the result of your query, and how `.Select(AsFirearmDto)` is projecting it to your Dto.

Comment: @FrankFajardo, thanks, i will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this change to my code, and it now works. Thanks Guys.

```
[Route("olderthan/{lastupdate}")]
        public IQueryable<FirearmDto> GetFirearmsByDateolderthan(DateTime lastupdate)
        {
            return db.Firearms
                .Where(f => f.LastUpdate < lastupdate)
                .Select(AsFirearmDto);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your data format is not xml format. If this format is json, your content type must application/json. Please just check your content type and change it as application/json. I think it works.